# React Javascript displaying/decoding unicode characters in a <title> element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode, next.js

I dynamically load my `<title>` inside my react with nextjs:

```
<title>GHG talks&amp;#8217; Work, Play, and Snack&amp;#8217;s | Glass House Games</title>
```

As this is outside the normal react cycle I cannot use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is it possible to decode this?

Answer (score 0):

I went with a plain JS problem:

```
<title>{title.replace('&#8217;', "'")}</title>
```